# How can I put main title in the horizontal center of the whole plot window?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making horizontal bar plots with ggplot2. I would like to put the main title of the plot above the actual plotting area as usual, but center it horizontally to the whole width of the plot window. The default main title is centered horizontally to the width of the actual plotting area (with the bars and the grid).

The title can be moved horizontally by adjusting hjust values in

```
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))
```

but it doesn't seem to work nicely with multiple lines of title text.

Is there any way to move the main title to the horizontal center of the whole plot window?

Example:

```
factor<-c("short label 1", "short label 2", "longer label requires quite a lot of space", "short label 3", "short label 4")
freq<-c(16,15,25,28,17)
data<-data.frame(factor,freq)
ggplot(data, aes(x=factor, y = freq)) 
+ geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.5) 
+ coord_flip() 
+ labs(title = "Rather long title for the plot, requires quite a lot of space") 
+ theme_grey(base_size = 15) 
+ theme(text = element_text(family = "serif"), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15, colour = "black",  vjust=1), axis.text.y = element_text(size = 16, colour = "black", hjust=1), plot.title = element_text(vjust=1))
```

[example pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIlED.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this (using `gridextra`):

```
require(gridExtra)

factor<-c("short label 1", "short label 2", "longer label requires quite a lot of space", "short label 3", "short label 4")
freq<-c(16,15,25,28,17)
data<-data.frame(factor,freq)
g.plot<-ggplot(data, aes(x=factor, y = freq)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.5) +
coord_flip() +
theme_grey(base_size = 15) +
theme(text = element_text(family = "serif"), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15, colour = "black",  vjust=1), axis.text.y = element_text(size = 16, colour = "black", hjust=1), plot.title = element_text(vjust=1))

g.t<-textGrob(label="Rather long title for the plot, requires quite a lot of space",just=c("center","center"))
grid.arrange(g.t,g.plot,ncol=1,heights=c(1,15))
```

[image]

**EDIT** - as per comment from @Baptise, you can also use:

```
    grid.arrange(g.plot,main="\nRather long title for the plot, requires quite a lot of space")
```

or:

```
grid.arrange(g.plot,main=g.t)
```

Comment: Could you add that as an answer to the dupe I flagged, thus updating it?

Comment: @Spacedman - yes that's done

Comment: Thank you! And thanks also for the 'duplicate' marking. I missed that question while searching.